# how to make an image fit inside the board

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have code in which there is class box,  i have given `backgroundimage` to `class box box1`.

> **My problem** is that  the image is not correctly fitting inside to the board. When i resize the window it is moving upwards. How to
>   correct it?

How to make the image fit correctly inside the board without losing responsiveness **without extract the board element from the main background and use it as an element alone**?

which is the method to do this, when i try to make it fit inside the board it is not only fitting inside the box, but also losing its responsiveness..

```css
html, body {
 background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/K7mpxZG/background9.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55.3vh;
  left: -19.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
 height: 1.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}


.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
      
        <div class="box box1" id="box1"  style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);">
          <p name="values" id="name1" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What should fit in what? Your background image is being skewed depending on the aspect ratio of the viewport. Is that what you intend?

Comment: are you also this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10323673/jupiter ? or is this question a homework somewhere? ... there is a bounty on this question

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to `#container` and to `.container2` (parent) if you set `position:absolute` to child

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh529vsq/)

```css
html, body {
 background-image:url(https://i.ibb.co/K7mpxZG/background9.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55.3vh;
  left: -19.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
 height: 1.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}


#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border:px solid #CC0000;
position: relative;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30vw;
  position: relative;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}


.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
      
        <div class="box box1" id="box1"  style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);">
          <p name="values" id="name1" class="hidden"></p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: will change nothing, because we have a fixed position in an upper element and the container don't have any padding/margin... test you code and you will have the same output as his code

Comment: pay attention to that edit, you simply erased position:fixed with relative and screwed the layout because you have the default body margin ... and still the relative position on the inner container is useless

Comment: simply test your code with his code, changing position will not fix his issue ... you have the same output

Comment: @לבנימלכה@temani-afif  guys we are in a situation that we cant rework the structure of the code , becoz a lot of code working on top of it........is there any possible solution there  i can achieve this  without changing the main structure of the code...

Comment: @temani-afif guys we are in a situation that we cant rework the structure of the code , becoz a lot of code working on top of it........is there any possible solution there i can achieve this without changing the main structure of the code...